# Is this proof that $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational valid?

Tags: proof-writing, radicals, irrational-numbers

I was doing some grading and came across the following proof that a student gave for $\sqrt 6$ being irrational:

> Assume $\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb Q$. Then $\sqrt{6} = \frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb N$. Now, since $\sqrt{6} = \sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$, we have that $\sqrt{6} \in \mathbb{Q} \wedge \sqrt{6} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ which is a contraiction. Therefore, $\sqrt 6 \notin \mathbb Q$.

I think this argument is wrong because if we try the same thing for $64$ as an example, we find that

$$\sqrt{64} = \sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 32$$
which by the same argument shows that $\sqrt {64}$ is irrational but it obviously isn't.

I suppose I've just never seen an argument like this, and though the example pretty clearly shows it's wrong, I'm wondering if there's anything to it. Maybe a small tweak to make it work? Obviously it's not similar to the [standard method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207210/verify-my-proof-of-the-irrationality-of-sqrt6?rq=1) but I think it's creative and interesting nonetheless.

Comment: You're right. That's not a valid proof.

Comment: What is $G$ in this argument?

Comment: I'm guessing that in your question $G$ and $Q$ are meant to be $\Bbb Q$, right?

Comment: The argument doesn't seem to make any sense. What's the purpose of $a,b$? Where does $\sqrt{3}$ come into play? Grammar of student's proof is ambiguous as well

Comment: I don't understand your hesitancy (or lack of confidence) in marking this as invalid.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? Obviously the student's proof is wrong, I hope the question is not getting downvoted because the student made a mistake.

Comment: @ClydeKertzer  What's with the upvotes? Was it your student or you who used three different symbols for the rationals? Not only is the proof obviously wrong the presentation is extremely poor for a student at this level. I don't see how a grader would have any problem with marking this wrong.

Comment: Are you asking how much partial credit should probably be given? Given that the student wasn't clear of their probable assumption that irrational times irrational is irrational, and also $a,b$ not being used, I'd give it a low score (or none) if I was grading it

Comment: Having seen your most recent edit, I don't myself see any creativity, just confusion. But I wouldn't say this to the student of course. RyRy seems to express the matter well and in kind terms.

Comment: the OP is able to provide a clear counterexample to the student's proof, so i don't think he is wondering whether or not the proof is correct. he appears to be wondering if perhaps it could be tweaked or improved in some way so that it becomes correct. i don't see it though.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I suspect that some downvotes might be due to the title, which asks a question where the answer should obviously be 'no' for anyone teaching the course. A better title might be whether the invalid proof can in some way be tweaked into a valid one.

Comment: @user43208 fair observation. the title could be improved to reflect the heart of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your student seems to be assuming the following: if a number $n$ can be written as a product in which at least one factor is irrational, then the number $n$ is irrational. Of course, this is not true, and you have found a very instructive counterexample.

Comment: Not to mention that even if $a$ irrational somehow implied $c$ is irrational for $c=ab$, then there is absolutely no value in invoking the proof by contradiction setup.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio great point!

Comment: Take any prime $p$, then $sqrt(p)$ is not rational, and $p$ is not rational by the student's logic..